# Could not install package 'FormsPinView 1.1.0'. in Xamarin forms

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library

I am trying to install Device LockScreen FormsPinView package in Xamarin forms using PCL but its not install in my PCL project.
and facing the below error while doing so.

Could not install package 'FormsPinView 1.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project to `.NET Standard 2.0` it will solve the issue described above and will help you in many other ways. There are 4 simple steps that you have to make and they are described in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/063a35fe3986e62d69aee2f0ed0607bf), however if you are using `Visual Studio for Mac` you could automate the conversation process by using extension called [Mutation](https://github.com/yuv4ik/Mutatio).

You can find more details [on the official Xamarin blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/).

I also wrote a short [article](https://smellyc0de.wordpress.com/2018/03/12/reducing-the-amount-of-code-by-switching-to-net-standard/) on this topic.

Good luck.